# classify image with caffe

Tags: computer-vision, classification, caffe, pycaffe

I am trying to build a binary classifier using Caffe. First I trained my own image dataset by slightly modifying *Fine-tuning for style recognition* model. But when I try to classify a single image, it gives 50% probability for both of the classes. To classify, I used the same deploy.prototxt, just changed output_number to 2. This is strange, since while training I get accuracy ~85%. I tried both python (classify.py) and cpp (classification.cpp), and both give same result. I think I am doing something wrong with the pipeline.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Did you train it on the prototxt after changing the output_number to 2?

Comment: @malreddysid, I trained it using the configuration "Fine-tuning for style recognition", there output_number is 2. while testing, I used deploy.prototxt after changing output_number: 2.

Comment: Was your input for the network when classifying also processed(normalized or subtracted with mean) with the way same as training?

Comment: @DaleSong, I think so. the cpp classifier that comes with caffe takes a mean file as input, and there is a line in `Preprocess(..)` method that does a `cv::subtract(..)` using input image and the mean file.

Comment: I noticed that during training, different mean values are subtracted from different elements in the same channel of the input, while in `classification.cpp`, a mean value which is an average of the former mean values is substracted from all those different elements. They are different.@Rakib